# How to use json data from localhost in objective-c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    NSURL *site_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/json/data/post?sid=%@", SECURE, PASSCODE]];

    NSData *jsonData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:site_url];
    NSError *error = nil;
    NSDictionary *dataDictionary = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];

    self.items = dataDictionary;


}
```

I am trying to parse json data. It works fine with data from the live server. However, when I change the link to `http://localhost:8090`. It stops working.

```
Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
```

I can access it from the data from the web browser. Does anyone know why is that?

Comment: your jsonData is nil, can post a NSLog from your jsonData

Comment: NSLog just show jsonData: (null)

Comment: Are we talking about the simulator or an actual device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does it work on emulator and not on a real device?

You should never use localhost when developing apps, use the local IP for the server instead. Localhost is the machine who make the call to the server. When you try on the emulator and you have the server on the same machine it works because they are the same.
But when you try on a real device, localhost is the device, and the device doesn't have a server installed, so it will fail.
BTW, to test on a real device, it has to be connected to the same network.

Comment: I was quite blunt to figure it out.  Thanks very much, you're right about this.

Answer (score 1):

What you need here is to implement the NSURLConnection and receive data from it

Check out this

```
NSURL *site_url = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/json/data/post?sid=%@", SECURE, PASSCODE]];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:site_url];
NSURLConnection *con = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:req delegate:self];
[con start];
```

and from the delegates get the response

this [document](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) can help you a lot in this